# Replace new line + 4x space to new line in stdout

Tags: bash, text-processing, string

I need join 2 lines into one in `stdout` - replace new line AND 4x space with one space but new line without space don't touch

```
tcpdump -vvv ... -l | xyz
```

this is output:

```
2014-06-06 AAA
    BBB
2014-06-06 CCC
    DDD
```

but I need:

```
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD
```

Comment: This feels like a Mexican stand-off. I'm upvoting everybody - these are all awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought of another way to do this that doesn't rely on paired lines but instead only a `<space>` character following a `\n`ewline character:

```
sed ':n;N;s/\n  */ /;tn;P;D'
```

That uses a sliding window of newline data and the `t`est function to operate. The flow is like this:

1. define the `:n`ext label
2. append `N`ext line in input to pattern space
3. `s/`elect a `\n`ewline character followed by 1 or more `<space>` characters and replace them with a single `/<space>/`
4. `t`est if last `s///` was successful and, if so, branch to `:n`ext label, else...
5. `P`rint up to the first `\n`ewline character in pattern space and...
6. `D`elete up to and including first `\n`ewline character in pattern space and restart cycle with remaining pattern space or with next line

So, basically, all occurrences of `\n [ ]*` in input get squeezed into `[ ]`:

```
sed ':n;N;s/\n  */ /;tn;P;D' <<\DATA
2014-06-06 AAA
    BBB
2014-06-06 CCC
    DDD
2014-06-06 EEE
2014-06-06 FFF
    GGG
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD
2014-06-06 EEE
2014-06-06 FFF GGG
```

#### OLD:

```
sed -n 'h;n;H;x;s/\n */ /p' <<\DATA
2014-06-06 AAA
    BBB
2014-06-06 CCC
    DDD
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD
```

I use 5 `sed` commands.

1. overwrite `h`old space with pattern space...
2. overwrite pattern space with the `n`ext line in input
3. append pattern space to `H`old space following an automatically inserted `\n`ewline character
4. e`x`change the contents of hold and pattern spaces
5. `s/`elect the first `\n`ewline character and any or `*`all following spaces then `/`replace the selection with a single space and `/p`rint the result.

Though, now that I think about it, a simplified version of both mine and @Falsenames answers - which really is better than this one - would just be:

```
sed 'N;s/\n */ /' <<\DATA
2014-06-06 AAA
    BBB
2014-06-06 CCC
    DDD
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD
```

Comment: A label at the beginning of the script is unneccessary, as a missing label is interpreted as start of the script. So one can write `sed 'N;s/\n  */ /;t;P;D'`

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -v ORS= '/^ {4}/{print substr($0,4); next}
     {print s $0; s="\n"}
     END{print s}'
```

That one should work for inputs like:

```
2014-06-06 AAA
    BBB
2014-06-06 CCC
    DDD
    EEE
2014-06-06 EEE
2014-06-06 FFF
```

And produce:

```
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD EEE
2014-06-06 EEE
2014-06-06 FFF
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n {4}/ /g'
```

But that means slurping the while input in memory first.

Answer (score 5):

Editing this to give more error correction.

The 'N' command in sed appends the next line.  Using this in conjunction with a substitution to swap out the newline and a bunch of the spaces with nothing.

```
$ cat foo | sed 's/^/    /'
2014-06-06 AAA
    BBB
2014-06-06 CCC
    DDD
2014-06-06 EEE
2014-06-06 FFF
    GGG
```

My new answer:

```
$ sed ':a;$!{N;s/\n   //;ba;}' foo
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD
2014-06-06 EEE
2014-06-06 FFF GGG
```

That seems to be far superior to my old answer:

```
$ sed '/^[^ ]/N;s/\n   //' foo
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD
2014-06-06 EEE
2014-06-06 FFF
    GGG
```

Or the pretty slick one @mikeserv listed.

```
$ sed -n 'h;n;H;x;s/\n */ /p' foo
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD
2014-06-06 EEE 2014-06-06 FFF
    GGG
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. I love screwing with this stuff - experimenting just like you have. I don't know what drove me to do all of that crazy stuff in the first place - I think I was counting on `$(date) ...\n` for *every* line and I  was going to strip the second `$(date)` *and* the `\n`ewline. Anyway, I think mine works even in the last line case - which I didn't handle because they were always supposed to be paired - to handle odd cases without recursion you could do this: `sed '/^[0-9]/!{H;$!d};x;s/\n */ /g'` though I use the method you demo quite often as well.

Comment: I always run into issues with h/H.  Just starting to learn some of the more advanced control stuff with sed.  I use the basics often enough at work that it's nearly embarrassing to be unfamiliar with the control ranges.  That last modification of yours here works great.

Comment: I think the `H` one breaks depending on whether the last line is an odd or even case - cleaning that stuff up is usually the annoying bit. `P,D` make it much easier, but you have to think about them differently. `info sed` has some examples - usually they `H` the first 5 or 10 lines or so then `x` and just `N;P;D` till eof - always keeping 10 or so lines in pattern space. If I can offer you any advice though - debug with `l` - especially if you're having trouble with hold/pattern space. *My* problems there usually have to do with not clearing it after use.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo "2014-06-06 AAA
      BBB
2014-06-06 CCC
    DDD
" | paste - - | tr -s '[:blank:]' '[ *]'
```

```
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` command,

```
$ awk '{var=$0; getline; print var,$1}' file
2014-06-06 AAA BBB
2014-06-06 CCC DDD
```